# how to declare variables in svg

Tags: xml, svg

I am trying to learn SVG at the moment.
This is the url from where I get my info:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/03/25/jump-loader-animation-svg-gsap/

As you can see at "The Structure and Layout" there are some variables. Where do I put them? Do I use the `<script>` tag or is there a whole other way to do this in svg?

this is my code right now:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<div id="container">
 <svg version="1.1" id="loader" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 150;" xml:space="preserve">

  <style type="text/css">
   .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
   .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  </style>

  <script  type="text/javascript">var</script>
  
  <path id="jump" class="st0" d="M34.7,107.8c0-36,29.7-65.6,65.5-65.5c35.6,0.1,65,29.4,65.1,65.1"/>

  <g stroke="#2d2d2d" stroke-width="1"> <!-- [** ! **] de <g> tag groepeert alles wat er in staat. de attributen welke je hier in zet (vb een stroke) geven dit door aan alle "child elements". -->
   <ellipse id="circelL" class="st1" cx="34.4" cy="109.5" rx="14.4" ry="3"/>
   <ellipse id="circelR" class="st1" cx="165.3" cy="109.5" rx="14.4" ry="3"/>
  </g>

 </svg>
</div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The code with those "variables" is written in Javascript.  You should look for some tutorials on how to use Javascript in your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution!
You copy the code from the svg and paste it into your html page. when you do that you can make the `<script>` tag and start adjusting the svg.

Thanks guys for your help!